# Discord JDA GatewayIntent.GUILD_MEMBERS usage?

Tags: java, discord

I'm attempting to add the GUILD_MEMBERS GatewayIntent to use the onGuildMemberJoin listener however the program "finishes with exit code 0" when I do this:

```
private static void login(String token) {
    try {
        JDABuilder
                .create(token, GatewayIntent.GUILD_MESSAGES, GatewayIntent.GUILD_MEMBERS)
                .addEventListeners(new Listener())
                .build();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If I remove GUILD_MEMBERS the bot starts up and runs fine.

My listener class is simply printing a value to test if they are firing:

```
public class Listener extends ListenerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void onReady(@Nonnull ReadyEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Bot is now running!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onGuildMessageReceived(@Nonnull GuildMessageReceivedEvent event) {
        System.out.println("message received");
    }

    @Override
    public void onGuildMemberJoin(@Nonnull GuildMemberJoinEvent event) {
        System.out.println("user joined");
    }
}
```

Any ideas? No exception is thrown and I haven't been able to find a solution on google.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's a simple fix. On the JDA Github page regarding [Gateway Intents](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/Gateway-Intents-and-Member-Cache-Policy) they specify that you must:

Due to GUILD_MEMBERS being a privileged intent you must also enable it
in your developer dashboard:

1. Open the application dashboard
2. Select your bot application
3. Open the Bot tab
4. Under the Privileged Gateway Intents section, enable SERVERMEMBERS
   INTENT.

Comment: I recommend you setup a proper slf4j implementation because it does log an exception. I recommend logback-classic. You probably have slf4j-nop which you should remove.